# how to use random function to execute another function?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem using the random function, I can't run any other function using the random function. below is the code I use:

```
def function ():
        
        
        c = (function(), functionb())
        d = random.SystemRandom()               
        run(d.choice(c))
```

I also tried using the secrets function and experienced the same thing What should I do to create a function and run other functions randomly?

Comment: this only generates one function only and not randomly

Comment: You're executing your functions when you create `c`. If you want to build a pool of functions to run, don't use `()`: `c = (function, functionb)` - if this isn't what you mean, please clarify what you're asking about (like what you expect to do and see).

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how to do it:

```
import random

def foo():
    print("foo")

def bar():
    print("bar")

collection = [foo, bar] # use the function objects, not the results of running
                        # the functions, in a list
d = random.SystemRandom()
d.choice(collection)() # choose a function and run it
```